# OrderByChild not working - Xamarin Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: c#, xaml, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I want to add a search function on my project in my MainPage.xaml file. It all went well with zero errors until I add the SearchRasepiRecord() method that queries the Firebase database based on the search term.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private async void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var searchTerm = e.NewTextValue;
    var records = await firebaseHelper.SearchRasepiRecord(searchTerm);
    displayRecord.ItemsSource = records;
}
```

FirebaseHelper.cs:

```
public async Task<List<RasepiRecord>> SearchRasepiRecord(string searchTerm)
{
    var result = await firebase
        .Child("RasepiRecords")
        .OrderByChild("Food")
        .StartAt(searchTerm.ToLower())
        .EndAt(searchTerm.ToLower() + "\uf8ff")
        .OnceAsync<RasepiRecord>();

    return result.Select(item => new RasepiRecord
    {
        Name = item.Object.Name,
        Food = item.Object.Food,
        Ingredients = item.Object.Ingredients,
        Instructions = item.Object.Instructions,
        Meal = item.Object.Meal,
        Socmed = item.Object.Socmed,
    }).ToList();
}
```

I got the same error, which is:

> Error CS1061  'ChildQuery' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByChild' and no accessible extension method 'OrderByChild' accepting a first argument of type 'ChildQuery' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have the tried the below adjustment but still got the same error.

1. Using the right directive

```
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Database.Query;
```

2. Already install the latest version of Firebase Realtime Database .NET SDK
3. Try uninstalling it then installs it again
4. Also tried cleaning and rebuilding my project

*I'm using VS2019 btw, does it effect anything…

Comment: From what location did you get the "Firebase Realtime Database .NET SDK" that you're using? Also, can you edit your question to show how you initialized the `firebase ` variable?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [code](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/e7e628af78fd9f1655762911890766d048a3bf46/src/Firebase/Query/QueryFactoryExtensions.cs#L39) in the [`step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet` repo](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet), it seems like this method might by called `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByChild`. So give it a try with:

```
.OrderBy("Food")
```

---

Looking at the code a bit further, it expects a `Func<String>`, so it might need something like:

```
.OrderBy(() => "Food");
```